# Graphic card switching delay

Tags: macbook-pro, graphics, gpu

I got this MacBook Pro 15" 2016 with Radeon. And every time it switches graphic cards there is a delay for like 10 seconds.

How do I know this? I have installed [gfxCardStatus](http://gfx.io) that displays a notification every time the card is switched.

For instance logging in to Gmail is like this, open a login page, the card is switched to Radeon 455, wait 10 sec, back to Intel HD, wait a little bit more, finally you can proceed. It becomes a real nuisance when you need quickly log in and out of different Gmail accounts as you get blocked every time you reach the login page.

Open a gfx editor... wait again. You get the idea. It only works okay when connected to an external monitor and Radeon is always in use.

Apparently, this is not something everybody is dealing with because I don't see people complaining left and right. Should the switching be pretty seamless?

There seem to be less delay when it falls back to Intel HD, but switching to Radeon is unbearable. If I open, say, a graphics editor, the cursor disappears for 6-10 seconds and it looks sort of depressing as notebook hangs as well.

Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: The switching *should* be seamless, yes. There might be a very slight jolt in cursor movement, but that's it, nothing as bad as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

It was driving me crazy but in the end, after a few updates, everything went back to normal.

It might not switch back to the integrated card on battery even if nothing is using a dedicated one, but that is another issue.